# Angular 2 service - How to return an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular2-services

I have Angular 2 service component that populates an array of objects.  I want to get that array from other components in the program.  But, in the code shown below getUsers() always returns null.

How can I make getUsers() return the array that was populated in populateUsers()?

Service Component code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ContainerUser } from '../models/container-user';
import { ContainerService } from './container.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
private _containerUsers: ContainerUser[];
private _currentUserId: string;
private _currentUserName: string;
errorMessage: string;

constructor(private _containerService: ContainerService, private _router: Router) { this.populateUsers(); };

populateUsers() {
    this._containerService.getContainerUsers()
        .subscribe(
        users => {
            this._containerUsers = users;  <--The array is good here.
        },
        error => {
            this.errorMessage = error;
            if (error.includes("expired")) {
                alert("Login has expired.");
                this._router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        });
}

getUsers() {
    return this._containerUsers;  <--This returns null.
}

setCurrentUserId(userId: string) {
    this._currentUserId = userId;
    var index = this._containerUsers.findIndex(i => i.login === userId);
    this._currentUserName = this._containerUsers[index].name;
    document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = this._currentUserName;
    document.getElementById('loggedIn').innerHTML = 'selected.';
}

getCurrentUserId() {
    return this._currentUserId;
}

getCurrentUserName() {
    return this._currentUserName;
}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand why you are using this kind of data flow pattern? I think the most convenient way for doing this is working with an observable. Use an observable. Send a message to that observable from the success of `populateUsers` method. Then subscribe for that observable from the component you want.

Comment: You may be right.  I don't know.  Can you show me how you would implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest I have found is to convert your http calls to a `promise` and then use `async` and `await`. This is what I have done in my own solutions:

```
async populateUsers() {
    this._containerUsers  = await this._containerService.getContainerUsers().toPromise();  
}

getUsers() {
    return this._containerUsers;
}

async ngOninit() {
    await populateUsers();
}
```

I really like this pattern because it simplifies everything, no need for callbacks.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try this.  But, it looks to me like it will populate the array every time I call getUsers().  Which is not what I want to do.  I want to populate the array one time and then get the already populated array every time I call getUsers().